# Sitemap not redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, yoast

Need a little help, I have a website and I have activate SSL to that,
Everything is on SSL except the sitemap page, it’s automatically redirecting to http:// mode rather than https mode.I have to type https manually to view sitemap page in https mode.
For this I am having search console error.Search console can read sitemap but it’s showing http error.How to redirect http to https automatically.Here’s my .htaccess code though.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am using yoast SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable HTTPS. I thought Yoast would do that for you. It could be browser cache?

Try adding this to the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```